# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity! RAILS API with POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I trying post a json file with Rails API.
I have try to fix but can't run
This my problem:

## Sever log:

```
Started POST "/students/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-17 17:45:33 +0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"student"=>{"name"=>"Duong", "score"=>"10"}, "registration"=>{"student"=>{"name"=>"Duong", "score"=>"10"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Unpermitted parameters: name, score
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (10.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (60.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 442ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

## Student.rb

This is my student model

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

## Application_controller

I have fix excetion => null_session

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

end
```

## Student_controller

```
class Api::StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    students = Student.all
    render json: students, status: 200
  end
  def show
    response_with Student.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    student = Student.new(student_params)
    #if you save successfully than response with json data and status code 201
    if student.save
      render json: user, status: 201, location: student
    else
      render json: {error: user.errors}, status: 422
    end
  end
  private
  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:name, :score)
  end
end
```

## router.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :students
  namespace :api, path: '/',constraints: {subdomain: 'api'} do
    resources :students, only: [:index, :show, :create]
  end
end
```

But, when I send a post to api.1312100.com/students/

```
{"student": {"name": "Duong", "score": "10"}}
```

have a error:

```
500 internal server error
```

Comment: Do you have 
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in your <head></head>?

Comment: Where in <head></head> ?

Comment: I cant say much about CSRF error. but you have to fix the `Unpermitted parameters: name, score` error. try whitelisting those parameters i.e name and score

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Api::StudentsController` add:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: Thks a lot, but have still: `Unpermitted parameters: name, score`

Comment: you call ``students/`` using Post method , for api you can use your api controller for that call ``/api/students/``  using post method

Answer (score 7):

**Curling:**

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"student": {"name": "Duong", "score": "10"}}' http://api.1312100.com/students/
```

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format != 'application/json' }
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end
```

Comment: that's a sexy application controller you got there. 

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me...So ideally, you need to add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` at **every** controller that is using json format, rather than adding it into the `base_controller` or `application_controller`, else it wont work.

Initially I too added into the api/v1/base_controller.rb but still it was showing the same error of `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.`, then I experimented and added in two of my api/v1/sessions and api/v1/registrations controller and then it worked.

I am using Rails 7 with ruby 3

Comment: Is it safe? I think anyone can use the API like this?