# How to emulate curl requests in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to test that a PUT to an endpoint (`products/:id`) works, but when I try

```sh
curl -X PUT -d listing_id_created=True localhost:3000/products/27
```

it gives [`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3364492/5783745), which I now realise is the expected result (since there's no authenticity token provided since the PUT is coming from curl and curl doesn't know anything about it).

So my question is how do I run some simple curl `PUT`s (or any other verbs) to check that endpoints work correctly? Is the only solution to simply [disable/skip the authenticity token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594406/5783745)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546794/2325924

Comment: @7urkm3n does that mean it only protects from forgery if it's not a json response? Is that safe ? as in, couldn't a CSRF attack simply send json my way and mess up my database?

Comment: @7urkm3n I can confirm that the curl request now succeeds. I am still uncertain as to whether it's wise though?